# How to $bucket multiple collections coming from previous $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, bucket

I want to process the result of a $group, separately, in a $bucket function.

My data:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "The Pillars of Society", "artist" : "Grosz", "year" : 1926, "type": 1}
{ "_id" : 2, "title" : "Melancholy III", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1902, "type": 1}
{ "_id" : 3, "title" : "Dancer", "artist" : "Miro", "year" : 1925, "type": 1}
{ "_id" : 4, "title" : "The Great Wave off Kanagawa", "artist" : "Hokusai", "type": 1}
{ "_id" : 5, "title" : "The Persistence of Memory", "artist" : "Dali", "year" : 1931, "type": 3}
{ "_id" : 6, "title" : "Composition VII", "artist" : "Kandinsky", "year" : 1913, "type": 3}
{ "_id" : 7, "title" : "The Scream", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1893, "type": 2}
{ "_id" : 8, "title" : "Blue Flower", "artist" : "O'Keefe", "year" : 1918, "type": 2}
```

What I need to do:

1. Group by type -> Return 3 groups
2. Bucket by range of years EACH group returned in 1
3. Get the stats of each bucket in 2, for each group in 1

I want to process all in a single query, without running many times a "match" to filter by type.

Expected output:

```
{
    "1": {
        1900: [{ "_id" : 2, "title" : "Melancholy III", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1902, "type": 1}],
        1925: [{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "The Pillars of Society", "artist" : "Grosz", "year" : 1926, "type": 1}, { "_id" : 3, "title" : "Dancer", "artist" : "Miro", "year" : 1925, "type": 1}],
        "other": [{ "_id" : 4, "title" : "The Great Wave off Kanagawa", "artist" : "Hokusai", "type": 1}]
    }
    "2": {
        1900: [{ "_id" : 8, "title" : "Blue Flower", "artist" : "O'Keefe", "year" : 1918, "type": 2}],
        1925: [],
        "other": [{ "_id" : 7, "title" : "The Scream", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1893, "type": 2}]
    },
    "3": {
        1900: [{ "_id" : 6, "title" : "Composition VII", "artist" : "Kandinsky", "year" : 1913, "type": 3}],
        1925: [{ "_id" : 5, "title" : "The Persistence of Memory", "artist" : "Dali", "year" : 1931, "type": 3}],
        "other": []
    }
}
```

I know how to execute a bucket, a group and a match but I don't know how to combine it in the same aggregation pipeline to get the expected result without repeating the match query (what is possible,for example, using $facet).

Answer (score 2):

A similar output can be achieved with this pipeline:

```
db.artwork.aggregate([
    { $bucket: {
        groupBy: "$year",
        boundaries: [1900, 1925, 1950],
        default: "Other",
        output: { titles: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}
    }},
    { $unwind: "$titles" },
    { $group: {
        _id: { type: "$titles.type", year: "$_id" },
        titles: { $push: "$titles" }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        type: "$_id.type",
        year: "$_id.year",
        titles: 1
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { type: "$type" },
        buckets: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        type: "$_id.type",
        buckets: { year: 1, titles: 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which gives:

```
{
    "type" : 1,
    "buckets" : [
        {
            "year" : 1900,
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 2, "title" : "Melancholy III", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1902, "type" : 1 } ]
        },
        {
            "year" : 1925,
            "titles" : [
                { "_id" : 1, "title" : "The Pillars of Society", "artist" : "Grosz", "year" : 1926, "type" : 1 },
                { "_id" : 3, "title" : "Dancer", "artist" : "Miro", "year" : 1925, "type" : 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "year" : "Other",
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 4, "title" : "The Great Wave off Kanagawa", "artist" : "Hokusai", "type" : 1 } ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    "type" : 2,
    "buckets" : [
        {
            "year" : 1900,
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 8, "title" : "Blue Flower", "artist" : "O'Keefe", "year" : 1918, "type" : 2 } ]
        },
        {
            "year" : "Other",
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 7, "title" : "The Scream", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1893, "type" : 2 } ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    "type" : 3,
    "buckets" : [
        {
            "year" : 1900,
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 6, "title" : "Composition VII", "artist" : "Kandinsky", "year" : 1913, "type" : 3 } ]
        },
        {
            "year" : 1925,
            "titles" : [ { "_id" : 5, "title" : "The Persistence of Memory", "artist" : "Dali", "year" : 1931, "type" : 3 } ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The project stages are mainly to format the data, but the important thing here is to first get all the data that will be used to group the items (the classification per lapses is the only thing from the output that we don't have yet), separate each item with **$unwind** , and nest the arrays by using **$group** stages.

The output you want can be achieved with **$cond** operators, but it wouldn't be dynamic, as you would have to explicitly write the fields. More information about this can be found on this post [MongoDB aggregate group array to key : sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643327/mongodb-aggregate-group-array-to-key-sum-value)